# Looking for a PHP script that has this following functionality

Tags: php, open-source

I'm looking for a PHP script that has this following functionality, preferably open source so I could add more functionalities.

At least 4 types of users:

1) Admin - Me has access to all.

2) Group Manager - Can create new topic, upload multimedia files like (videos, audio, docs, pdf, etc.) and attach it to a certain topic they have created, approve viewers to view its created topic

3) Viewers - this are registered users only the website and their only function is to view the topic created by the Content Manager, they are limited to the topic where the Content Manger has approved them to view.

4) Guest - any unregistered users has very limited access, can only see contents that are tagged as for public

Functionality:

1) User registration for Content Manager and Viewers which needs approval from the Admin.

2) Can have multiple Group Manager, and each Group Manager is limited to the topic it has created. Which means it can't edit / delete nor see a topic that he has not created.

3) A Group Manager can upload any multimedia files he like and attach it to any of the topic he created.

4) A viewer user needs to ask permission to view a topic and download its content. Group Manager needs to approved the viewers who could view a topic. Approval is based on topics. A viewer needs to be approved on all his topics if he wants it all to be viewable to the user.

It doesn't have to function exactly the same way, I could modify it to fit my need so it needs to be Open Source free or not.

Also what do you call this type of software?

**Added:**

I know about the popular CMS like Joomla, Drupal, Wordpress, etc. But I'm not sure they could do the #2 on the functionality list above, definitely not Joomla at least. Once you logged in at the backend you could see the whole content regardless of who uploaded it.

Basically each Group/Content manager will have it's own people under it, it's own group of people who registered just to get the content of it's group manager he is following. Each Group/Content Manager will be a different person who doesn't know each other so it's really important the content they created and uploaded remained anonymous to each other.

Comment: Basically, that's a CMS. Something like Drupal or Joomla if you're looking at publishing mostly "static" pages. Wordpress if it's more blog-oriented.

Comment: I've already worked with Joomla before but I don't think it can do the #2 and #4 functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by typo3. It is a professional open source content management system. Maybe a bit complicated, but very good. http://typo3.org/

Comment: Can typo3 do functionality #2 and #4 out of the box? I mean without creating your own module/component to do it.

Comment: It has it out of the box, but it does not work automatically as simple as you described it. You have to configure the different groups in your admin backend. That for it is highly flexible. This is one of the advantages of typo3 vs joomla. Typo3 has different user groups and right management. Does Joomla have it nowadays as well? I remember times when it was lacking of this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need a CMS. My vote would go to [Silverstripe](http://silverstripe.org/stable-download) - simple to set up (& upgrade), great interface, has extensions for most things, good underlying code structure with easy to understand templating, produces standards-compliant code, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress will do everything you asked for http://wordpress.org/ and a lot more, and it's free.

Comment: Can Wordpress do functionality #2 and #4 out of the box? I mean without creating your own module/component to do it.